# Why do they call it a player?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Dont get the reason behind why they call it a player in build settings.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Unity3D is a interpreted development environment. You send the same file to Windows as you do to Android. The thing that changes is the program that reads that file and runs it on the machine.

The name of the program that reads your project file and runs it is called the "Player" because it "Plays" the file. This is similar to a "Flash Player" that plays flash files on the internet. The "Unity Player" plays unity files on whatever device you send it to.

Comment: thanks for the great answer